# function not present when calling

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing

I have implemented the leptonica library within my xcode project (Objective-C) and it has worked well until I tried calling a bunch of new functions that are not present. The problem is that I can see that these functions are defined in the header file with the hundreds of other functions so I do not know why it cannot be found. The exact error message is:

```
 Error in pixReadStreamPng: function not present
```

I have attached a small image of how my header file looks and you can see the function  seems to be defined. It is the allheaders.h file

[image]

I have also attached my code. Does anyone know why I cannot call the function? Thank you!

```
NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,   NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *pngFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.png",docDir];
NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
[data1 writeToFile:pngFilePath atomically:YES];

FILE *libFile = fopen([pngFilePath UTF8String],"r");

l_int32 one=300;
PIX *pixg;
PIX *pixB;
PIX *pixs= (PIX *) malloc(sizeof(PIX));
pixs=pixReadStreamPng(libFile);
pixg = (PIX *) malloc(sizeof(PIX));
pixg=pixConvertTo8(pixs, 0);
l_float32 scorefract=0.1f;
pixOtsuAdaptiveThreshold(pixg, one, one, 0, 0, scorefract,NULL,&pixB);
```

.a files for leptonica
[image]

Comment: Yeah, there is only function declaration. Are you sure that the function is defined ?

Comment: @MidhunMP I believe it is. The problem is the source is pre compiled to object archive (.a file) so I cannot fully verify. I have edited my question to show what I mean. Thank you!

Comment: Are you certain you compiled the Leptonica library with support for PNG?

Comment: @Chuck Thanks for the reply. No I am not 100% certain but I have tried the other functions as well (Bitmap, JPEG etc etc) and I get the same message. Considering this version of Leptonica was compiled to be used with Tesseract (OCR engine), I would assume it would support at least some image formats. Thanks!